# m2 release plugin couldn't recognize assembly file with parameterized name

Tags: jenkins, maven-release-plugin

In my POM.xml file, I am using assembly plug in. I want the build to assemble things based on the assembly file, whose name is parametrized. The build works fine. However, if I use m2 release plug in using perform release action in jenkins, the release plugin could not substitute the value for $env and pick up the assembly.xml file. I get the following exception.

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.AssemblyReadException: Error locating assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/${env}.xml

I have attached the log and POM file.

POM file build portion:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>dist</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuraenter code heretion>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/${env}.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```